# Java API to list dataflow job

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to write java code to list the dataflow job.
I have taken reference from https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs/list
But the 'GoogleCredential' Class is deprecated. I tried replacing `GoogleCredential`  to `GoogleCredentials` but at this below line

```
Dataflow dataflowService = new Dataflow.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
      .setApplicationName("Google Cloud Platform Sample")
      .build();
```

it expects HttpRequestInitializer instead of credential.

Can anyone help me how can I use credential itself and fix this issue?

Comment: `HttpRequestInitializer` is made mandatory for a reason. What is stopping you from creating a `HttpRequestInitializer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpRequestInitializer` is required to perform automatic retry upon failures. A simple `HttpRequestInitializer` can be constructed using `com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential` as follows:

```
private HttpRequestInitializer buildInitializer(Credential credential) {
    return httpRequest -> {
      // handles abnormal HTTP responses (non 2XX responses)
      final HttpUnsuccessfulResponseHandler unsuccessfulResponseHandler =
          new HttpBackOffUnsuccessfulResponseHandler(new ExponentialBackOff())
              .setSleeper(Sleeper.DEFAULT);
      /*
      this is designed to work with only one HttpRequest at a time.
      Hence, a new instance of HttpBackOffIOExceptionHandler with new instance of
      BackOff is created for each instance of HttpRequest
      */
      HttpBackOffIOExceptionHandler httpBackOffIOExceptionHandler =
          new HttpBackOffIOExceptionHandler(new ExponentialBackOff()).setSleeper(Sleeper.DEFAULT);
      httpRequest.setInterceptor(credential).setUnsuccessfulResponseHandler(unsuccessfulResponseHandler)
          .setIOExceptionHandler(httpBackOffIOExceptionHandler)
          .setConnectTimeout((int) TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(3))
          .setReadTimeout((int) TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(3))
          .setThrowExceptionOnExecuteError(false).setSuppressUserAgentSuffix(true);

    };
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. I helped me a lot.